# Regular expressions - different string the same match

Tags: python, regex

I understand that the pattern `r'([a-z]+)\1+'` is searching for a repeated multi character pattern in the search string but I do not understand why in case `k2` answer isn't 'aaaaa' (5 'a'):

```
import re
k1 = re.search(r'([a-z]+)\1+', 'aaaa')
k2 = re.search(r'([a-z]+)\1+', 'aaaaa')
k3 = re.search(r'([a-z]+)\1+', 'aaaaaa')
print(k1)  # <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='aaaa'>
print(k2)  # <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='aaaa'>
print(k3)  # <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='aaaaaa'>
```

Python 3.6.1

Comment: Explain step by step what your current reasoning is. Otherwise it's impossible to say what is really tripping you up.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a good site for working through RegEx (I'm not affiliated!)

Comment: It has to be an even number of characters because you repeat a thing twice. It's twice because `+` is greedy, and the first one has precedence.

Comment: The length of `(x)x` cannot be odd, no matter how many `x`s you have.

Comment: It's because `+` is greedy. It's trying to match as much as possible. Either change it to `([a-z]+?)\1+` or use anchors `([a-z]+)\1+\b`

Comment: Just a fyi, this `([a-z]+)` will match the exact amount and content that this `\1` does. Therefore adding a `+` quantifier to `\1` does not match more than group 1 matched, it's impossible. This also result's in an even match. If you change it to `([a-z])\1+` it will match 2 or more of what was captured in group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key notion here is *backtracking*. Whenever a pattern contains quantified subpatterns with varied length, the regex engine may match strings in various ways, and once a part of the regex after the quantified part fails to match some substring, it can *backtrack*, i.e. free up a char belonging to the quantified pattern and try to match with the subsequent subpatterns.

Have a look at the bigger picture:

[image]

**Let's see how shorter strings match before jumping at the longer examples...**

Now, why `a` is not matched? Because there must be at least 2 chars since `[a-z]+` and `\1+` require to match at least 1 char.

`aa` is matched since the first `([a-z]+)` matched the whole string first, then backtracked to accommodate some text for the `\1+` pattern (and it matches the second `a`), so there is a match.

Three-`a` string `aaa` matches as a whole because the first `([a-z]+)` matched the whole string first, then backtracked to accommodate some text for the `\1+` pattern (note the capturing group had to only hold one `a` as when trying with two `aa`, the `\1+` failed to match the final third `a`), and there is a match of three `a`s.

**Now, coming to the examples in the question**

The `aaaa` string matches in its entirety is a similar way the `aa` matched: the capturing group pattern grabs the whole `aaaa` at first, then backtracks since `\1+` also must "find" some text, and the regex engine tries to capture `aaa` into Group 1. However, `\1+` fails to match 3 `a`s, so backtracking goes on, and when there are two `a`s in Group 1, the quantified backreference matches the last two `a`s.

**And the `k2` case now:**

The `aaaaa` string matches like this:

- `aaaaa` is grabbed and placed into Group 1 with the `([a-z]+)` part
- `\1+` cannot find any text, the engine retries to match the string differently as the part before the `\1+` can match a different text thanks to the `+` quantifier
- `aaaa` is tried (=placed into Group 1), to no avail since `\1+` does not match (as then `\1` tries to match `aaaa`, but there is only `a` left before the end of string)
- `aaa` is tried, again, to no avail (as `\1` tries to match `aaa`, but there are only two `a`s left)
- `aa` is put into Group 1, `\1` matches the third and fourth `a`s, and that is the only match since only one `a` remains in the string.

Here is a [sample scheme of how the string is matched](https://regex101.com/r/ef5O4l/1/debugger):

[image]

The last `a` cannot be matched:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for thorough explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. Just FYI: the red arrows in the images denote a backtracking step.The green highlighted text is the part of the pattern that is currently tried. The blue selection is the text that matched the currently tried subpattern.

Answer (score 6):

Because + is greedy.

What happens is `([a-z]+)` first matches 'aaaaa', then it backtracks until `\1+` matches the string, and stops. Because 'aa' is the first value of the `([a-z]+)` that will let `\1` successfully match, that's what it returns.